# How to set maintenance mode Magento2

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I am getting below error to enabling maintenance mode by adding a file `var/.maintenance.flag`

> Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.  0
>   /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->assertMaintenance() 1 /index.php(49):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   2 {main}

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Two methods to disable the maintenance mode

### Via command line

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

### Via the files

Delete `var/.maintenance.flag`

Official documentation: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html#instgde-cli-maint

Comment: This not answer to why the exception is thrown

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to disable maintenance mode

If there is var/.maintenance.flag, Magento 2 maintenance mode is on.

For activating maintenance mode with ip addresses execute below command in CLI

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable --ip="..." --ip="...."
```

the above command will automatically create a .maintenance.flag and .maintenance.ip file under root/var folder.

and .maintenance.ip file contains the above two ip addresses separated by comma.

For ref. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html#instgde-cli-maint